# Facebook API posts photos

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook api to grab all the posts from a public page. Everything works great except for the photo they provide is very low quality and small. How do you modify your graph api query to get a better quality photo?

This was the original query I used to obtain an access token in the graph explorer:

```
1650393515218783?fields=posts
```

After reading similar questions and some documentation I tried this query

```
1650393515218783?fields=posts,picture.type(large)
```

But this still returned a low quality photo. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

This may help

[developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/)